# Complicate leftjoin conditions using eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel-4

I have a complicated query, not able to write it using eloquent

SELECT *
FROM `all_reports`
LEFT JOIN `activity_logs` AS `AL` ON (`all_reports`.`id` = `AL`.`type_id`
                                      AND (AL.user_id = 
                                           OR AL.user_id IS NULL))

Please help with the above query.
Thanks :)

Comment: You are not asking for  help, but solution. Show us some code, some effort.

Comment: You can take advantage of http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres